# How to get both my friends & friends of friends?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get friends of mine as well as friends of friends but limited to 2nd degree friends

My table structure will be something like this

```
user_id  friend_user_id
1            2
1            4
2            3
2            4
2            5
3            7
```

What i need is, if my user id is '1' then i want all my immediate friends (in this case 2&4) and user_is 2 has some friends (3,4,5) and the expected result is 2,3,4,5

How can i get that?

Comment: Where is the jquery in this ?

Comment: I can't see what your question has to do with jQuery, so I removed the tag.  If you think jQuery is relevant to your question, by all means edit your question to explain the connection to jQuery and add the tag back in.

Comment: @Andy E Sorry , when i selected 'Query' tag the 'jquery' tag got selected accidentally.. Thanks for editing..

Comment: @Intersteller_Coder Sorry , when i selected 'Query' tag the 'jquery' tag got selected accidentally..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a union and an inner join:

```
select friend_user_id from friends
where user_id = ?
union
select f2.friend_user_id from friends f1
join friends f2 on f2.user_id = f1.friend_user_id
where f1.user_id = ?
```

This should perform very well (much better than using a sub-select anyway).

Comment: ? if the mysql optimizer is worth it's satlt, the subselect should be rewritten to your query and they should perform the same. It's not a correlated subquery, so pushing it down is very simple.

Comment: Actually, I think you are correct: I'm pretty sure mysql automatically turns the subquery version into the join version

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT friend_user_id 
FROM table
WHERE user_id = 1 OR user_id IN (SELECT friend_user_id FROM table WHERE user_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT friend_user_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1
UNION
SELECT friend_user_id FROM friends WHERE user_id IN (SELECT friend_user_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1)
```

This will give you a set with all friends and friends of friendsof user with id 1, with duplicates removed. You can easily extend this for 3rd, 4th, etc. by nesting the queries using the IN clause.